# rmarkdown::render does not render an rgl::plot3d figure (but Knit button does!)

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, rgl

Consider the following example:

````
       ---
       title: "Untitled"
       output:
         pdf_document: default
       ---

       ```{r, setup}
       Sys.setenv(CHROMOTE_CHROME = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe")
       options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)
       rgl::setupKnitr()
       ```

       Plot:

       ```{r, rgl = TRUE, dev = "png"}
       rgl::plot3d(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
       ```
````

Running `rmarkdown::render("temp.Rmd", output_format = "pdf_document")` produces a PDF with no figure. Even more interestingly, hitting the Knit button in RStudio produces a perfect PDF! (Which is quite strange itself; I was under the impression that the Knit button is exactly the same as the above call.)

Comment: I had to comment out your `Sys.setenv`, but then both methods gave the same result for me.  So no idea why they were different for you, except maybe we're using different versions of software as well as different OS; I'm on MacOS.   I'd advise against using `rgl = TRUE`; use `rgl::setupKnitr(autoprint = TRUE)` and then you won't need any chunk options to get the plot to print.

Comment: Now that's really strange, but with `rgl::setupKnitr(autoprint = TRUE)` (and without `rgl = TRUE`), it is working perfectly for me as well! Although we didn't really figure out what was the cause of the problem, if you'd transform this comment into an answer, I'd happily accept it.

Comment: Basically the `rgl = TRUE` hook hasn't been supported for a few years, and won't be updated in the future.  It should probably generate a warning nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `rgl = TRUE` works with the `hook_rgl` function, which is one of the older ways of handling `rgl` in `knitr`.  It was always problematic, so recent releases have recommended other approaches instead.

Using `rgl::setupKnitr(autoprint = TRUE)` is the easiest one.  It approximates the behaviour of base plotting:  minor updates to a plot won't appear, only the final version is shown.  If you don't want that, then you can leave it with `autoprint = FALSE`, and explicitly include `rglwidget()` calls to get a plot to appear.

The auto-printing isn't perfect, e.g. some packages that produce `rgl` plots don't produce output in a way that will trigger it.  You can read more about this in the `?rgl::setupKnitr` help topic.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one last question: am I right to assume that I need `options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)` before `rgl::setupKnitr(autoprint = TRUE)`...? I receive an error without it.

Comment: The `rgl.useNULL` setting is optional.  If `rgl` runs on your system and displays within R, then the default `rgl.useNULL=FALSE` should display the plots from your document in R as they are produced.  However, that won't work if you are working remotely or on a system with no OpenGL support, and then `rgl.useNULL=TRUE` is required.